# How to display a video from an S3 bucket in React Native?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, expo, arraybuffer

I am trying to download a video from an S3 bucket and pass it to Expo's [Video component](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/). I am using `s3.getObject()` and the callback function to get the object as an `ArrayBuffer`. But I don't know how to use this data from this point. I tried concatenating `"data:video/mp4;base64," + videoData.body` and passing that as an object. I also tried converting it to `Base64String`, which also didn't work.

```js
let videoData = {}
const downloadIntro = async () => {

  s3.getObject(bucketParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error:" + err)
    } else {
      console.log(data.ContentLength)    // 1210362
      console.log(data.ContentType)      // video/mp4
      console.log(data.Metadata)         // Object {}
      console.log(data.Body.buffer)      // ArrayBuffer []
      videoData.body = data.Body.buffer
    }
  })
}

export default function App() {

  let [vidData, setVidData] = useState(null)

  const playVideo = () => {
    console.log("Trying to play")
    setVidData({video: "data:video/mp4;base64," + videoData.body})
  }

  return (

    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

      <Button title={"Load Video"} onPress={downloadIntro}/>
      <Button title={"Start"} onPress={playVideo}/>

      <Video
        source={vidData}  
        rate={1.0}
        volume={1.0}
        isMuted={false}
        resizeMode={"contain"}
        shouldPlay={paused}
        isLooping={false}
        style={{
          width: 300,
          height: 300
        }}
      />

    </SafeAreaView>

  );
}
```

Comment: What type of video? Is this HLS, DASH, MP4...?

Comment: @BentOnCoding MP4

Comment: What video engine (shaka, dash.js, etc..)? You should be able to set the url of the asset as the source of the video or pass it to your video engine. Unless you are building your own video engine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to put the raw video data in the source. Try just setting the attribute to the url of the video :

```
<video controls width="250">

    <source src="/media/cc0-videos/flower.mp4"
        type="video/mp4">

</video>
```